# Ant Colony Optimization or Genetic Algorithm for percentage based problem

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, ant-colony

So I've recently become really fascinated with algorithms in general. And I recently implemented an ant colony optimization algorithm to solve the TSP (very fun obviously). Now I've been looking at other "problems" to solve. Now I wanted to implement an algorithm to solve a problem involving fulfilling a percentage requirement, and to be below an arbitrary limit.

For example:

User input:

1) limit 
-i.e. amount of energy available to spend.

2) "chromosome" types
-i.e. blue(subtypes - indigo, etc), red(subtypes - maroon, etc), yellow(subtypes - light yellow, etc)
-each primary attribute like blue has a "pool" to choose from which consist of different subtypes like indigo, light blue, sea blue whatever.
-each sub type of color has a varying cost associated to it.

3) percentage of types required for the "ideal" solution (can introduce a +/- % to allow for more variety).
-i.e. 10% red, 30% blue, 60% yellow.

Output:

1) possible final solutions which fulfill the two requirements, being below - but close to the - required cost and meeting the percentage requirements of supertypes.

So for example.

This is a super simple example, obviously it'd be more complex than this in reality.

User specifies cost should be as follows 
95 <= cost <= 105.

User chooses 25% blue, 25% yellow, 50% red.
with +/- 5% deviation

Available pools for each color

**Blue:**
Indigo: cost = 25;
Sea blue: cost = 30;
Navy Blue: cost = 75;

**Yellow:**
Light yellow: cost = 20;
Dark yellow: cost = 30;
Super dark yellow(lol): cost = 75;

**Red:**
Maroon: cost = 20;
Blood Red: cost = 45;
Bright Red: cost = 55;

So the algorithm would run and return different combinations.

Combination 1: indigo, dark yellow, blood red: cost = 100: blue = 25%, yellow = 30%, red = 55%.

Combination 2: sea blue, light yellow, blood red: cost = 105: blue = ~30%, yellow = ~20%, red = ~50%

Combination 3: so on and so forth.

**EDIT:** Second edit

Output would consist of sets of different combinations.

For example, one solutions might consist of combinations like:

One solution would be represented by this:

Combination 1: Cost = 20; 50% blue, 25% yellow, 25% red;

Combination 2: Cost = 30; 10% blue, 50% yellow, 40% red;

Combination 3: Cost = 50; 25% blue, 25% yellow, 50% red;

Solution: = (combination 1, combination 2, combination 3) total cost = 100, and it consists of x% blue, y% yellow, z% red;

compare solution to requirements, if its close keep it, if not discard it.

**END EDIT**

So my question is. I know a genetic algorithm would work. But would an implementation of ACO work as well? For example, blue, yellow and red would equal "locations", then their subtypes would represent different "roads".

Just wondering what might be a more efficient solution or maybe some different algorithm entirely. I'm pretty new to this stuff and just started reading about it a little over a week ago.

**EDIT:** First edit

I want to specify that I want to have 5 good unique solutions (5 being an arbitrary number, could be 3, could be 20).

Comment: For your color problem, any linear optimization algorithm will do (eg. simplex, interior point, ...)

Comment: I can suggest another interesting problem for you to solve with ACO: resource leveling (sometimes called CRSP). Similar to TSP. E.g. Given a software development team and a work-plan where tasks depend on each other for completion and each task is assigned to a specific person, find the schedule that gets the project to finish earliest.

Comment: I just realized that I asked my question wrong zzz I ment to state that candidate solution is a set of combinations fulfilling the initial requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Your color problem seems pretty trivial to me, even brute force would be fast, I guess.. so your ant colony most probably can solve it too :)

Comment: Yeh the example is simple, but i think a problem in running time can arise when instead of having 3 colors. It becomes 5+ supertype requirements and each supertypes having hundreds or even thousands of subtypes to chose from.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see with your representation for the ACO, is the +/- X% .

**With a fixed percentage of each color, you could just proceed as you said:**

*Blue yellow and red are the locations
The different subtypes represent roads, and their weight depend on the cost and the pourcentage needed.*

Then you just apply your AOC method as for the TSP, but changing a bit how the ants move:

1. adding pheromones to one path only if it fullfills the constraints
   of cost
2. Selecting the path length closest to the "optimal length" = N% of
   the optimal cost (in the example above, for the yellow path, the one
   closest to 25%*95)

**If you want to add the floating percentage constraint then:**

let's say you're best cost is:

```
Cost = X1*light yellow +X2*sea blue+X3*blood red for example.
```

if this cost is not optimal you can work with some small varations on X1 X2 and X3, to optimize your cost:

for example X1-e and X2+e would change your cost by `e*(costseablue-costLightYellow)`

For example, given one small epsilon, for each pair Xi,Xj such that `costi<costj` (the cost of color linked to i and j) you can try adding epsilon to Xi and deleting it from Xj until you cannot improve the cost for all couples of Xi,Xj.

Comment: Ok, so implement ACO with FIXED percentages first, if cost is not optimal enough, then start creating variance in the percentages until an optimal cost is reached?

Comment: @Odnxe Yes it should work fine with ACO this way. You just need to add some constraints to the way Ants move since you're not looking for the smallest path. I guess not putting pheromones on unwanted path should be enough but I'm not sure. You can add a constraint on the path selection chosing the path closest to N% of medium cost .

Comment: Hmm, maybe ACO isn't the best option then because I'm trying to achieve multiple good but unique solutions - emphasis on unique. I wonder if instead of tracking of the best solution - I could track some arbitrary number of possible solutions, like 5 for example. That way I can employ 5 different "types" of ants that drop different kinds of pheromones, and the behavior of the ant would be to try to avoid the pheromone dropped by other types ants at all possible costs, unless no other option is available. This way I can guarantee 5 unique good solutions. What do you think?

Comment: @Odnxe That's an interesting way to proceed. I guess it should work and your constraint on uniqueness should be respected. But since the algorithm is not exactly the basic ACO, I'm not sure it will converge all the time. Adding new constraints (like the pheromone one) might make the algorithm not converge anymore... But I think you should give it a try, it's a pretty nice way to solve this problem.

Comment: What about just running it 5 times instead of the 5 ant type approach? It seems like the sort of problem where initial conditions would play a significant role.

Comment: I edited my question because I realized that I didn't present the whole problem. Its under the second edit portion. I don't know if that changes anything though. Now I'm wondering if this is now a two part problem. One where I create the potential candidates, then the second part is where I combine them to find suitable solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If your graph satisfy the triangle inequality I suggest you to try a minimal spanning tree and a perfect-weight-non-bipartite matching algorithm. Christofides et al. guarantee you a solution within 3/2 of the optimum. An AOC can give you good and fast result, but you have to optimized it for many problems. I've wrote a Christofides algorithm in php (phpclasses.org). You are welcome to try it out. I'm not sure if it's working. It give sometimes strange results. It's maybe my implementation of the Fleury algorithm?

Comment: A lot of that stuff went over my head, so I'll have to research a lot of those terms. But just glancing at each of those, the perfect-weight-non-bipartite matching algorithm looks like it might be a good match for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: It's difficult stuff, the matching-algorithm I'm using is one I've found in the internet. You might take a look at this tsp solver in javascript, it uses a k2-opt algorithm to search for swappable edges in the solution: http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-tsp-solver/